# Hiding a Dynamically Populated Div when Empty -- Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I've seen this question answered a number of ways, but none of the answers given work in my project. My application displays the user's previous choices in several divs. At the start of the application, none of the divs are populated. As the user answers questions, each of his/her previous answers are displayed in a div, until the user reaches a result page.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to hide the divs until they are populated.

My previous attempts have mostly centered around jQuery's `$('.div:empty').hide`, with no luck. Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Views/Layouts/_user_choices.html.erb**

```
  <div class = "default_test" id = "first_bar" >
    <% if @category != nil %>
            <p><%= @category.title %></p>
        <% else %>
            <!-- the div remains empty -->
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

**assets/javascripts/application.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.default_test:empty').hide();  // this does not work
});
```

Comment: An empty div has no visual relevance on the screen. It's not shown the users at all. So you don't have to worry about having to hide it.  I'm not sure why you would need to take the extra effort to hide an empty div. 

Are you facing any issues with the current approach? A screenshot/ fiddle will help me understand the issue better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at this page about [:empty](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/), it appears that **neither of these will match :empty**

DIV with a space

```
<div> </div>
```

DIV that closes on a different line:

```
<div>
  <!-- test -->
</div>

<div>
</div>
```

**Here is what you want your div to look like to use :empty**

```
<div></div>
```

or

```
<div><!-- test --></div>
```

Maybe try this, eliminating the line returns and extra spaces:

```
<div class = "default_test" id = "first_bar" ><% if @category != nil %><p><%= @category.title %></p><% else %><!-- the div remains empty --><% end %></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer -- and it seems pretty ridiculous. Just take this:

```
<div class = "default_test" id = "first_bar" >
    <% if @category != nil %>
           <p><%= @category.title %></p>
    <% else %>
           <!-- the div remains empty -->
    <% end %>
</div>
```

...and eliminate all the spaces and put everything in one line.

```
<div class = "default_test" id = "first_bar"><% if @category != nil %><p><%= @category.title %></p><% else %><!-- the div remains empty --><% end %></div>
```

For whatever reason, it works in this format, but not in the first format version. Literally the exact same code, just spaced out differently. If there is a smarter way to go about this, I'm all ears. Seems a bit strange that it should work ONLY in this manner.